# DTM: _satellite not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm using a Non-Sequential HTML Javascript/Third Party tag, where I'm using the following script to pass data to a 3rd party tag.

```
<script>
   x = _satellite.getVar('Sub-Total');
</script>
```

The problem that I have is that no data is passed to "x".

I have also tried the following:

```
<script>
   var x = $('td[data-hook="order_item_total"]').text().substring(1);
</script>
```

In this case I'm getting *$* is undefined. Note, both methods work when I test it in the Javascript console and if I use a Non-Sequential Javascript tag.  What do I need to add to make either of these work?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ridder

Comment: So are you getting a `_satellite not defined` error, or is it just returning undefined on the data element call? Do you have the data element ("Sub-Total") setup / have a value set to it? For the second part, do you have jQuery included before the DTM script include?

Comment: @MisterPhilip - To answer your questions: I'm getting a "_satellite not defined error".  I have a data element ("Sub-Total") and it returns a value.  I have tried including jQuery before the DTM, as well as changing $ for jQuery in the statement.

Comment: So you're getting a `_satellite not defined error` from code that originates from a tag in DTM? Are there any other errors on the page? What does setting DTM into debug mode show (run `_satellite.setDebug(true)` and reload the page to see console output)? Do other rules get loaded?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is when you configure your tag to be **Non-Sequential HTML**, the code is output dynamically in an `iframe`. Since the `iframe` doesn't include the `_satellite` object, attempting to reference it results in an `undefined` error.

If your tag contains a blend of html and javascript that needs to be output and you need `_satellite` exposed, you need to instead use a **Sequential HTML** tag.

Alternatively, if the code in your tag is really purely javascript and just happens to be wrapped in `<script>` tags, then simply remove the `<script>` tag wrapper and put the code in a **Javacript** style tag (It doesn't matter if it's sequential or non-sequential; both will have `_satellite` exposed to it) .

**Note:** I could find no mention of this in the DTM documentation (though I could be blind!), but If you open your browser's developer console and look at the live/rendered DOM, you can verify this yourself. I feel like at a minimum this caveat should at least be mentioned in the documentation.